# Number of solutions of the equation $a-z-e^{-z}=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

I am trying to calculate the number of solutions of the equation $a-z-e^{-z}=0$, with $a\in \mathbb{R}, a>1,$ that are in the semiplane $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Re(z)>0\}$.

I have tried using Rouché's Theorem and the Argument Principle but the fact that the function in the equation is not a polynomial is making it difficult for me to apply these results.

It would be very helpful if anyone could give me a hint as to how to apply these theorems in this case or point out a different approach in case using the results I have thought is not viable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $R>a+1$ and let $\Gamma$ be the contour consisting of the semicircle in the half-plane of radius $R$ and the straight line $[-iR, iR].$ We now apply the Rouche's theorem with $f(z)=a-z$ and $g(z)=e^{-z}.$

First observe that $|g(z)|\le 1$ on $\Gamma.$ Check that $|f(z)|>1$ on $\Gamma.$ It follows that $a-z-e^{-z}$ has the same number of zeroes in the Half-plane as $a-z.$ (In fact it also tells us that the zero is contained in $\{|z|\le a+1\}\cap \{Re(z)>0\}.$) Note that $z-a$ has exactly one zero in the half-plane.

Also as an aside note that $h(z)=a-z-e^{-z}$ is real on the real line and $h(0)>0$ and $h(a)<0.$ This tells us that the zero of $h$ is actually a real number in $(0, a).$